# Regex with backslash in String doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I want to split my text using regex.
for example, I have the String:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8,9,10
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8,9,10
1,2,3
```

I want to split my string like this:

first cell of array:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8,9,10
1,2,3
```

second cell of array:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,7,7,8,9,10
1,2,3
```

for that, I want to use regex.

My delimiter is my first 2 lines

So I have trying this following regex:

```
(.*,){6}.*\s(.*,){9}.*
```

But it doesn't work for me... And don't understand why.

If someone can give me an explain..

And after split, I want to keep my delimiter in my array. Because delimiters are removing after split.

Thanks

EDIT:

I will show you my application (I have resume that by numbers, but it's more complexe) and I have a string like that :

```
LB,32736,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T194400.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
LB,32734,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T201200.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.6743068099021912,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.6744459867477417,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.6745882630348206,192
20190811T080300.000Z,0.6747232675552368,192
20190811T080400.000Z,0.6748600006103516,192
20190811T080500.000Z,0.6749916672706604,192
20190811T080600.000Z,0.6751362681388855,192
```

And I want to have 
In the first cell :

```
LB,32736,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T194400.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
```

In the second cell :

```
LB,32734,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T201200.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.6743068099021912,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.6744459867477417,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.6745882630348206,192
20190811T080300.000Z,0.6747232675552368,192
20190811T080400.000Z,0.6748600006103516,192
20190811T080500.000Z,0.6749916672706604,192
20190811T080600.000Z,0.6751362681388855,192
```

Maybe it's better to use Regex Matcher/Pattern of Java library than split function

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the requirements: you have a multiline string and want to split that after the 3rd line? Is that it?

Comment: @Thomas I don't think so. I think the OP wants to use the first two lines as delimiters.

Comment: Do you want to match the first 3 lines?

Comment: @Sweeper hmm, that example is a little misleading since it seems that the "delimiter" and the 3rd line should be in the same string - and the string contains 2 identical halves anyway.

Comment: You may match the items using `(?sm)^[^,\n\r]*(?:,[^,\n\r]*){6}\R[^,\n\r]*(?:,[^,\n\r]*){9}$.*?(?=\R[^,\n\r]*(?:,[^,\n\r]*){6}\R[^,\n\r]*(?:,[^,\n\r]*){9}$|\z)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GjTnsc/2). However, it feels like you should not use a regex here.

Comment: @MathAng please show us what you've tried and also come up with some more (and easier to understand) examples. Do you _know_ what the delimiters look like? Do they all have the same structure? How many lines could be between delimiters? What can those lines look like (could they be confused with delimiters?)?

Comment: The regexp is probably in a String notation. Java needs escaping for the backslash. So the regexp should be \\s

Comment: Note: **if** you are using the `split()` method, the delimiter is **not** part of the result, it will be discarded

Comment: I have update with a real example.
I prefer to use regex, because type of string can be different, and I prefer algorithm wich is update with regex (define in my config) than modify my algorithm depending form of string

Comment: you *can* use *zero-width positive lookahead*  around all the expression to have it included in the `split`s -at least works fine for simple cases - (start regex with `"(?="` and end with an additional `")"`; e.g. `",abc,def,ghi".split("(?=,)")`) not sure if that is recommended (hard to read, understand, maintain, error prone). I would use Pattern/Matcher/find() to find where to split and use `substring()`

Comment: OK I will.
But regex expression above doesn't work. it return just the first match with java Pattern/Matcher ... I don't understand why

Comment: Perhaps like this `^(?:[^,\r\n]*,){6}.*\r?\n(?:[^,\r\n]*,){9}.*(?:\r?\n(?!(?:[^,\r\n]*,){6}).*)*` See https://regex101.com/r/LieuH6/1 or the longer version taking both lines into account as delimiter https://regex101.com/r/9AAOFM/1

Comment: @MathAng Was that helpful or is the logic different?

Comment: yes, it returns the first pattern, save its position, `find` next to find end of first segment, `find` next pattern for next segment.... until end - but seems like you are already working on a different solution

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is inserting a delimiter and utilizing Pattern's split.**
**Try this out:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "LB,32736,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T194400.000Z\n"
            + "TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2\n"
            + "20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192\n"
            + "20190811T080100.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192\n"
            + "20190811T080200.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192\n"
            + "LB,32734,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T201200.000Z\n"
            + "TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2\n"
            + "20190811T080000.000Z,0.6743068099021912,192\n"
            + "20190811T080100.000Z,0.6744459867477417,192\n"
            + "20190811T080200.000Z,0.6745882630348206,192\n"
            + "20190811T080300.000Z,0.6747232675552368,192\n"
            + "20190811T080400.000Z,0.6748600006103516,192\n"
            + "20190811T080500.000Z,0.6749916672706604,192\n"
            + "20190811T080600.000Z,0.6751362681388855,192\n";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(LB,\\d+,)", Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
    String stringWithDelimiter = pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("#$1")
            .replaceFirst("#", "");

    List<String> cells = Arrays.stream(Pattern.compile("#").split(stringWithDelimiter))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    cells.forEach(s -> System.out.println("\nCell:\n'" + s + "'"));
}
```

Output of **"cells.forEach(...):**"

```
Cell:
'LB,32736,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T194400.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_INST,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.00800000037997961,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.008999999612569809,192
'

Cell:
'LB,32734,0,T,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,20190811T080000.000Z,20190811T201200.000Z
TR,NRJ.POMPES_BACHE.PUISSANCE_ELEC_CPT,0,65535,1,1,,0,0,2
20190811T080000.000Z,0.6743068099021912,192
20190811T080100.000Z,0.6744459867477417,192
20190811T080200.000Z,0.6745882630348206,192
20190811T080300.000Z,0.6747232675552368,192
20190811T080400.000Z,0.6748600006103516,192
20190811T080500.000Z,0.6749916672706604,192
20190811T080600.000Z,0.6751362681388855,192
'
```